# Redirect public ip to domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I need that when someone enters my ASP.NET MVC / C# website typing its public ip in the browser, the user is redirected to the domain name.

Thanks

Regards

For example if I write 142.250.0.139, the browser redirects to google.com. I need that exactly to happen.

Comment: What’s your web server? You can likely have a canonical address there

Comment: Do you have a reverse-proxy in front of your application?

Comment: Not trying to not answer the question but I am curious: For what purpose? Why would it matter to the user who typed in the address that way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just redirect on page load. You can test for if it came from ip address or domain if needed.

Comment: I put this on Global.asax

 protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  
            if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"].Contains("[my website public ip]"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://[my domain]");
            }

        }

Resolved

Thanks tony95